# Set ng-model after rendering JSP page

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS, Spring MVC & JSP in a project. I need to do this kind of thing :

```html
<div class="hide" ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <span ng-model="myValue">${valueToRender}</span>
</div>
```

After rendering, let's say I get this HTML :

```html
<div class="hide" ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <span ng-model="myValue">42</span>
</div>
```

I would like, in the Angular Controller, to access the value of `myValue`, but the browser says that `myValue` is undefined.

Here is the javascript :

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
    console.info($scope.myValue); //Browser tells me that is undefined
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-model` is inappropriate for this, besides it only applies to input elements (not `<span>`s). I'd suggest using a directive:

Target markup:

```
<div class="hide" ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <span server-data="myValue">${valueToRender}</span>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module("...").directive("serverData", function() {
    return {
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope[attrs.serverData] = element.text();
        }
    };
});
```

This directive with the HTML template above would put the value `"42"` (string) in the scope, under the name `myValue`. (This code is untested just to demonstrate the general idea.)

But, are you sure this is the way to implement client-server communication?